# Where is the Puranic story of Sharangadhara receiving a dream from Shiva?

Tags: scripture, puranas

According to [**Dhanurveda**](https://www.atarn.org/india/dhanurveda_eng.htm), Śāraṅgadhara is "considered to be an expert in the knowledge of the Dhanurveda.

> 2. Nobody but Sarngadhara is considered to be an expert in the knowledge of the Dhanurveda, because he got his skill (in holding, aiming and shooting etc.) and judgment (for wind velocity and speed of the moving target etc.) in a dream at night from the Lord Siva Himself.

Where did this  story  of Sharangdhara occurs in detail? Are there any puranik references to this story